# How to establish foreign keys in a database

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, key, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a software that allows you to trace the relationships that exist between the tables in a database? In other words, a software which allows to establish foreign keys between two or more tables? Thank you

Comment: You put MySQL in the tag line but you may want to mention it in the question.

Comment: Navicat will do this..

Comment: @thebjorn I have .csv file of table, Navicat work fine with these files?

Comment: @LuigiEsposito no (Navicat will produce an ER diagram from tables in a database, including defined foreign key relations).  There is no magic wand (that I know of) that will divinate fkey relations from raw table data.

Comment: @thebjorn Unfortunately, all you do is point out what I already had ... wait for more information from other users. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you say "in other words" and then you ask a totally different question.

Is there software to ESTABLISH a foreign key relationship between two tables? Absolutely. It's called "SQL Data Definition Language" and it comes with every SQL product. You can create the relationship when you create the child table: After the field name and definition of the foreign key you put a "references" clause and name the parent table, like "create table city (city_id int, city_name varchar(40), country_id int references country (country_id))". You can also add a foreign key later, but then the syntax varies depending on the database product.

Is there software that lets you TRACE the relationships? That's a totally different question. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "trace". If you simply mean, "show me existing foreign key relationships", then sure. Different database products have different ways to do this, you'll have to look at your documentation. MySQL has the "show" commands that will display various information about your tables, including foreign keys.

Most databases today support the "information_schema", which is a set of database tables that describe the database. You can query this to get lists of foreign key relationships.

If you mean that you want pretty diagrams ... there are products out there, I've seen them, but I don't use them and can't give any recommendations.

*Update*

Okay, based on your comment, I think what you're trying to say is that you have a bunch of data with no foreign key relationships explicitly stated, and you want to find what the foreign keys might be.

I am not aware of any software product out there that does this. A little thought will show that the problem cannot be solved definitively. That is, we couldn't write software that would allow us to say we now know what the foreign keys are with 100% certainty.

The only way I see that you could do this would be to look for values in one column of one table that are always present in some column of another table. Like say that in table X, column 4 we find that the values are all "foo", "bar", and "plugh". Then we look at table Y and find 3 records, and column 1 contains the values "foo", "bar" and "plugh". I'd say there's a good chance that column 1 is the primary key of table Y and that X(4) is a foreign key pointing to Y.

But suppose instead we find that table X column 4 is an integer containing 1, 2, or 3. Table Y has 100 records with column 1 containing values between 1 and 1,000,000, including the values 1, 2, and 3. Is X(4) a foreign key to Y? Probably not. The fact that all the values in X(4) are found in Y(1) is probably just a coincidence.

If there are 100 different values of what we suspect is the primary key in table Y and only 95 of these are referenced from table X, that might still be a foreign key. There are often records that are unreferenced for a variety of reasons. But if only 10 of them are referenced ... now it's harder to say. Maybe and maybe not.

In general I'd suspect that common values in text fields are more meaningful than common values in numeric fields. Two fields both containing the value "3" proves little. Two fields both containing "bragnar" seems less likely to be a coincidence.

I think your best bet would be to attack this using intelligence and intuition. Load all the tables into a database. Then see if they have obvious primary keys. If you know what the data in the tables is really supposed to MEAN, you should be able to make some guesses about likely keys. Like if you know that this is a table of parts that your company produces, you can look for recognizable part numbers, etc. Look for fields that have no duplicate values. Like select x1, count(*) from x group by x1 having count(*)>1, if there are no such records, that might be the primary key. If there's any case where two records have the same value, it can't be the primary key. (Well, maybe you have to consider the possibility of bad data.) Then look for values in other tables that resemble these values. Do queries to see all the values from table X exist in table Y, like select * from x where not exists (select * from y where y.y1=x.x4).

You could, I suppose, write a program that would examine every column in every table and give you a list of those that were unique, and then examine every column in every table and give you a list of those whose values are all found in a unique value from another table. That would give you candidates. Then you'd have to see what makes sense.

Comment: Based on his comment, I was assuming he had a set of .csv files that he wanted to be automagically connected together. ..or maybe he just wants to visually draw lines (trace) between tables to identify fkeys..?

Comment: probably I was not precise in exposing the problem, now I try to do better.
I have 3 tables made:

table 1

A-B-C-D-E-F-G
0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7

table 2

A-B-C
8-9-3

table 3

H-I-L
03/10/11

@Jay I want to see if there is a foreign key between these 3 tables, knowing a priori that it exists, but that the information has been lost. The tables are in csv format, so they have little information to work on. I have been more clear now?